# Object rvalue propagation for member function calls

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I have a struct `F` with a function `foo` that has different implementation whether `F` is a temporary or not

```
struct  F{
  void foo() &  { std::cout << "F::foo() &" << std::endl; }
  void foo() && { std::cout << "F::foo() &&" << std::endl; }
};
```

Another struct `A` has a copy of `F` and in its function `bar` calls `F::foo`. I want to use the correct version of `F::foo()`. Therefore the implementation is:

```
struct A{

  void bar() & {
    f.foo();
  }

  void bar() && {
    std::move(f).foo();
  }

  F f;
};
```

I'm wondering if I really have to provide two implementations of `A::bar()`. Isn't there a smart way to use `std::forward` to automatically decide which `F::foo()` should be used?

---

An attempt:

```
struct B{

  void bar() {
    std::forward<F>(f).foo();
  }
  
  F f;
};
```

However, this does not work. It calls `F::foo() &&` every time.

---

### [Complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/q4Mfz3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a non-member function template:

```
struct B{

  template<typename TB>
  friend void bar(TB&& self) {
    std::forward<TB>(self).f.foo();
  }
  
  F f;
};
```

Depending on other function parameters, you might want to restrict the type of `TB` such that `is_base_of_v<B, remove_const_t<remove_reference_t<TB>>>`.

Comment: Awesome hack. I was looking for a `friend` based solution, too, but ended up with something less elegent. Nice!

Comment: @lubgr You just know too much C++17. For me, `if constexpr` is somewhere at the back of my mind and `forward` is much more present ;)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no shortcut available at this point and you will need to stick to the verbose version. But have a look at [p0847](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0847r0.html), "Deducing `this`". Not sure what the status of this proposal is, however. From the abstract:

> We propose a new mechanism for specifying or deducing the value category of an instance of a class. In other words, a way to tell from within a member function whether the object it’s invoked on is an lvalue or an rvalue, and whether it is const or volatile.